# Calling HTML files and Javascript from QML

Tags: html, qml

I have one HTML file which I need to call from QML. My HTML file uses ajax programming. I get an error saying "undefined variable $ ajax". Is there a library I need to use to solve this issue?

main.qml--From My main.qml file, I am calling boot.htm file. On my boot.htm file, I will call my javascript file.

```
Page{
    WebView {
        id: webView
        url: "local:///assets/boot.htm"
    }    
}
```

boot.htm

```
<div id="bootScreen" data-bb-type="screen" data-bb-scroll-effect="off"> 
<style type="text/css">

#bootScreen
{
   background:url('images/image.gif') no-repeat;  
}  
#logo
{
  height:200px;
  width:600px; 
}
</style>
<script id="bootJS" type="text/javascript" src="js/boot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "***",
        type: 'GET',
        data: { usr: localStorage["userName"],
            pwd: localStorage["userPassword"]
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#statusError').html('<center><div style="color:black !important; font-weight:bold font-size:20px"><img class="loading" src="images/loader.gif" align="middle" style="margin-bottom:25px;"/> LOADING</div></center>');
        },
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (data) {
            bb.pushScreen('login.htm', 'login');
            if (!isPlaybook()) {
                unlockOrientation();
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#statusError').html('An Error Has Occured. Please Try Again');
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(textStatus);
            localStorage.clear();
            bb.pushScreen('login.htm', 'login');
            unlockOrientation()
        }
    });
}, 5000);

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#logo').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('#logo').outerWidth()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('#logo').outerHeight()) / 2
    });
});

$(window).resize();

</script>
<div id="logo" style="display:none">
<img  src="images/image.gif" />
</div>                 
</div>
```

Boot.js

```
var service = "****";
var locked = false;

function rotateAndLock() {
if (!locked) {
    blackberry.app.lockOrientation('portrait-primary');
    locked = true;
}
}

function unlockOrientation() {
    blackberry.app.unlockOrientation();
    isLocked = false;
}
```

I am not able to see the image.gif on my app when I ran it. I get error saying $.ajax is undefined variable. Please advise.

Comment: please show what you have already tried, you could paste some code

Comment: I have updated the code. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

$ is commonly used as a reference to the jQuery library, which has a ajax library.

Comment: I am also happy if I could get any sample login page as I am new to HTML and Javascript. Please

Comment: Add <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> just in front of the bootJS script tag.  This will add the Jquery library asa  source for your project so it can be used.